# <a href=""> tag for login somehow disappears

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make some header in my web page but I have a problem. I've created some top menu with fixed position, where are placed links to social media and login link. But this login link is not displayed in my top menu.

HTML code:

```
<div id="body">
<header id="header">
    <div class="inner">
        <h1><a href="itw1.html"><span>FITLayout</span></a></h1>

        <div id="topmenu">
            <a href="#" class="login">Login</a>
        </div>

        <div id="social" class="icons">
            <a href="http://twitter.com/" class="twitter"><span>Twitter</span></a>
            <a href="http://www.facebook.com/" class="fb"><span>Facebook</span></a>
            <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/" class="linkedin"><span>Linked In</span></a>
        </div>

        <nav id="menubar">
        <ul id="menu">
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Company</a></li>
            <li class="selected dropdown"><a href="#">Products</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">News</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Downloads</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
</div>
```

And this is my CSS file:

```
#body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 900px;
}

#header {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}

#header .inner div {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    color: white;
    background-color: #5f5f5f;
}

#header .inner #topmenu .login {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-top: -10px;
    color: white;
}

#header .inner h1 {
    display: block;
}
```

[HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/bimbochobot/eoadud8r/5/) is link to jsfiddle to show you my problem.
Note: I can modify only CSS code, I cannot modify HTML.

Is there any solution please?

Comment: Syntax is not proper.

Comment: @Vinaya could you be more specific please?

Comment: specify what you want exactly in output?
I'll create sample code.

Comment: @Vinaya I want to see white login link on the right side of grey strip ( "menu" )

Comment: can I change your html code? because it seems incorrect syntax.

Comment: @Vinaya unfortunately no, it cant be modifyied.. but I'm pretty sure its correct, I have this from school.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108089/discussion-between-vinaya-and-petr-becka).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that social div is width 100% and it appears over the login. You can do this:

```
#header .inner #social{
    width: 70%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/eoadud8r/9/

Comment: Well, such a mistake.. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

This solution is working.

1. I gave CSS property to parent div of login.
2. Added position absolute to parent and gave z-index.

```css
#body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 900px;
}

#header {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}

#header .inner div {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    color: white;
    background-color: #5f5f5f;
}
#header .inner #topmenu{
  position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    width: auto;
}
#header .inner #topmenu .login {
    color: white;
}
#header .inner h1 {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="body">
<header id="header">
    <div class="inner">
        <h1><a href="itw1.html"><span>FITLayout</span></a></h1>

        <div id="topmenu">
            <a href="#" class="login">Login</a>
        </div>

        <div id="social" class="icons">
            <a href="http://twitter.com/" class="twitter"><span>Twitter</span></a>
            <a href="http://www.facebook.com/" class="fb"><span>Facebook</span></a>
            <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/" class="linkedin"><span>Linked In</span></a>
        </div>

        <nav id="menubar">
        <ul id="menu">
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Company</a></li>
            <li class="selected dropdown"><a href="#">Products</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">News</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Downloads</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The topmenu and login elements are overlapping each other. If you change the background to 'none' and the z-index to something more than 1, you will see login over the menu. I don't know if that was your intention.

Comment: background have to stay the same color and if I set `z-index: 2;` for example, it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the changes I made to get more or less what you had.

First I added the following rules:

```
.inner {
  background: white;
}

#menubar {
  background: white;
}
```

Then I moved the background from `#header .inner div` to `#header`. Then I updated `top` in `#header .inner div` to 10px.